# Issue with sprintf()

Tags: c, printing

```
int read_from(int client_index, struct sockname *usernames) {
    int fd = usernames[client_index].sock_fd;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE + 1];

    int num_read = read(fd, &buf, BUF_SIZE);
    buf[num_read] = '\0';
    /*
    if (num_read == 0){
        usernames[client_index].sock_fd = -1;
        return fd;
    }
    */
    char formattedOutput[BUF_SIZE * 2 + 2];
    sprintf(formattedOutput, "%s: %s", usernames[client_index].username, buf);
    for (int index = 0; index < MAX_CONNECTIONS; index++) {
        if (usernames[index].sock_fd != -1) {
            if (write(usernames[index].sock_fd, formattedOutput, strlen(formattedOutput)) != strlen(formattedOutput)){
                usernames[index].sock_fd = -1;
                return fd;
            }
        }
    }
    /*
    if (num_read == 0 || write(fd, formattedOutput, strlen(formattedOutput)) != strlen(formattedOutput)) {
        usernames[client_index].sock_fd = -1;
        return fd;
    }
    */

    return 0;
}
```

I don't want my program to print the second `%s`. Removing `buf` makes my program not print at all for some reason. I also tried changing the value of `buf` itself to an empty string.

Comment: Then just remove the second `%s` and `buf` from the `sprintf` call. Btw: you might want to use `snprintf` to avoid buffer over-runs.

Comment: What do you mean by "not print the second `%s`"?  You should probably close the socket before you mark it unusable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second '%s' to be optional, you can use one of the following techniques. Assuming **flag** is a Boolean that decides if to print buf or not.

```
sprintf(formattedOutput, "%s: %s", usernames[client_index].username, flag ? buf : "");
```

or

```
sprintf(formattedOutput, flag ? "%s: %s" : "%s", usernames[client_index].username, buf);
```